# Run PHP Remotely

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP script that i want to run on users sites remotely, that ties in with their account on mine. So basically it is software-as-a-service. The user would copy and paste certain code to their site and it would run strictly php. I am unsure how to do this.

Are you able to run php remotely and how would you do it if for example my site was:

mydomain.com

and the users domain would be:

customerdomain.com

Comment: Can your users run PHP on their servers?

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is create a web service. Basically a client application would send messages to your web service and get a response. This way it doesn't matter what languages the user has available on their server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Comment: You might want to have a look at CURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @dqhendricks this is true, but the PHP is extremely complex and the code cannot be seen on the client side

Comment: what I mean by client is, the client of the web service, which could easily be PHP on a server, or any other language.

Comment: users shold let you know address of the file with your php code. And then you just open it remotely (fopen, fsockopen etc)

Comment: @dqhendricks Services such as chartbeat.com require you to merely copy and paste some javascript onto your side to get the service working. This is what I want, but PHP.. Make sense haha?

Comment: Yep, it's exactly what I am talking about, and with a webservice it doesn't matter what talks to your webservice, a browser with javascript, or a server with PHP, since all that is being passed back and forth is data. You will have a lot more trouble getting people to let you place a PHP script on their server than a javascript snippet in their page however. Also, not everyone uses Apache/PHP. If you built a webservice, and gave documentation about how to authenticate and make calls to the webservice, they could build their own client using Java, .NET, PHP, Javascript or whatever.

Comment: @dqhendricks Ahhhhh true.. So I should basically create an API.. (web service)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat little trick for you that might be what you're looking for.  This file would be located on your server:

```
//yourfile.php
<?php

$output = "hello world";

header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
echo "document.write('$output');";

?>
```

Then your client would paste this code on their site, and it would output "hello world".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/yourfile.php"></script>
```

I use that trick to let people load widgets on their site without having to give them my PHP code.

Comment: that is cool! The only thing is that I will need to change the header information based on different outcomes of the script. Do a header redirect, etc. Will this still work? Thanks!!

Comment: Also, we're doing a lot with reserved $_SERVER variables. Will this work?

Comment: A header redirect won't work, you'd have to output a Javascript redirect or something.  $_SERVER would be your own server variable not theirs.

Comment: Can you do if statements and everything? @michael

Comment: You can do everything you normally would be able to do in PHP.  You can even put the source of the Javascript as http://mydomain.com/yourfile.php?foo=bar and in yourfile.php you would have access to $_GET['foo'] with the value of bar. As other people suggest you could also just do Ajax, but then you're giving the customer a boatload of code that they could potentially screw up. This method has the same effect as an Ajax call but it is idiot proof for the customer and a clean one-liner for them to paste in.

Comment: Thanks man. Only problem I just seen. Were comparing URLs and things, IP addresses and looking at the current IP, browser type, and killing the connection based upon these things. Do you think this would be the best way?

Comment: $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] in your PHP script would be the IP address of the person visiting your client's page, not the IP address of your client's server.  $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] would be the URL of your client where they pasted the Javascript.  $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT] would give you the browser of the person visiting your client's site.  I'm not really sure exactly what you're trying to do so it is hard to say.

Comment: yes thats what I meant. We can handle all of that, but we need a script included at the top of the clients page thats entire PHP just as if we were saying include('script.php');

Comment: Sounds like this trick will do exactly what you need then, except instead of being able to do things like a header redirect you'd have to echo out a Javascript window.location type of deal.

Answer (score 0):

As dqhendricks suggests, it sounds far better to keep the functionality of your system on your server and service data to customer sites via Javascript using an AJAX like communication channel. This route will enable you to display data from your system on their website.

Comment: I am unsure how to do this properly because all of the code that we have wrote in PHP doesn't translate to Javascript well enough to just have a customer do a javascript include

Comment: You could have a webpage that outputs JSON, then use javascript to read that data, process it and display it on the user's website. Effectively utilising both JavaScript and PHP. This is far easier than the customer needing a PHP module to communicate with your server, and would only require your customers to have a lightweight javascript file that reads content from your maintained webpage of data.

Comment: True.. I'll have to do some research. Thank you @Dan Belden

Answer (score 0):

You can't run php on their site, but you can set up a url on your end that users can query with cURL (for example) to send you their information and receive back whatever information you want to provide.

Comment: could you give an example? cURL has always been tough for me.